# Select rows where every child row meets a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle DB, I have two tables in a one-to-many relationship: Managers and Employees.

```
+------------+-------+------------+
| Manager_ID | Name  | Department |
+------------+-------+------------+
|          1 | Steve | Sales      |
|          2 | Ben   | Sales      |
|          3 | Molly | Accounts   |
+------------+-------+------------+

+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
| Employee_ID | Manager_ID |  Name  | Age |
+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
|           1 |          1 | Kyle   |  25 |
|           2 |          1 | Gary   |  31 |
|           3 |          2 | Renee  |  31 |
|           4 |          2 | Oliver |  32 |
+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
```

How do I select only those Managers where every one of his Employees is over the age of 30?

In my example data, the only Manager who meets this condition is Ben, because both of his employees are over 30.

I thought something like this would do it, but it's wrong:

```
SELECT m.manager_id 
FROM   managers m 
WHERE  m.manager_id IN (SELECT e.manager_id 
                        FROM   employees e 
                        GROUP  BY e.manager_id 
                        HAVING e.age > 30)
```

Comment: change having with where

Comment: The HAVING clause should be `having min(e.age) > 30` to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sub-query for counts

```
SQL> WITH manager(Manager_ID, Name, Department) AS (
  2    SELECT 1,  'Steve', 'Sales' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 2, 'Ben', 'Sales' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 3, 'Molly', 'Accounts' FROM dual),
  5  employee(Employee_ID, Manager_ID, Name, Age) AS (
  6    SELECT 1 , 1, 'Kyle', 25 FROM dual UNION ALL
  7    SELECT 2 ,1, 'Gary', 31  FROM dual UNION ALL
  8    SELECT  3, 2, 'Renee', 31  FROM dual UNION ALL
  9    SELECT 4, 2 , 'Oliver', 32  FROM dual)
 10  ---------------------------
 11  --- End of data preparation
 12  ---------------------------
 13  SELECT m.name
 14    FROM manager m
 15    JOIN (SELECT manager_id,
 16                 COUNT(1) total,
 17                 COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) age_30_above
 18            FROM employee
 19           GROUP BY manager_id) ee
 20      ON m.manager_id = ee.manager_id
 21   WHERE total = age_30_above;
```

Output

```
NAME
-----
Ben
```

Your query will be:

```
SELECT m.name
  FROM manager m
  JOIN (SELECT manager_id,
               COUNT(1) total,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) age_30_above
          FROM employee
         GROUP BY manager_id) ee
    ON m.manager_id = ee.manager_id
 WHERE total = age_30_above;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `not exists` :

```
select m.*
from manager m
where not exists (select 1 
                  from Employees e 
                  where e.Manager_ID = m.Manager_ID and e.Age < 30
                 ) and
      exists (select 1 from Employees e where e.Manager_ID = m.Manager_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I don't like about Yogesh's answer (which I upvoted, since it's probably the way I'd write it) is that you have to go to the `employees` table a second time, to make sure the manager actually has at least one employee.

On the plus side, the `NOT EXISTS` that Yogesh used will allow Oracle to stop looking at a manager's employees once it finds one that is too young.  So, maybe it's a toss-up.

I'll offer this alternative.  It is shorter than the `NOT EXISTS` and does not have to go to the `employees` table a second time.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM  manager m 
CROSS APPLY ( 
   SELECT min(age) min_age 
   FROM employee e 
   WHERE e.manager_id = m.manager_id ) ma
where ma.min_age >= 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT manager_id 
FROM   employees -- managers
minus
select manager_id
from   employees
where  age <= 30
```

Comment: That does not exclude Molly, who has no employees at all in the OP's sample data.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, you are right. Now it should be ok and Molly is excluded (see line with comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ALL function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions002.htm#SQLRF52085) like this:

```
SELECT m.manager_id 
  FROM managers m
 WHERE (30 <= ALL (SELECT e.age FROM employees e WHERE e.manager_id = m.manager_id));
```

Comment: That does not exclude Molly, who has no employees at all in the OP's sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reverse the conditions, select all managers, who dont have any employee below 30

```
select * from managers
where manager_id not in (select manager_id
                         from employees
                         where age < 30)
```

Comment: This is more dangerous than the other solutions.  If there is an employee under age 30 with a *null* `manager_id` (maybe your dynamic, young CEO), it will kill the whole query -- you will get no results at all, because no row is "not in" a list containing a `null` value.

Comment: Also, this doesn't exclude managers have *no* employees, like Molly in the OP's sample data.